# Highchart improper datetime in x-axis

Tags: highcharts

Im using highcharts for certain report but the following setting for option

> xAxis: {
>                   title: {
>                       text: xlabel,
>                       style: {
>                           fontSize: '14px',
>                           fontFamily: 'proxima-nova,helvetica,arial,sans-seri',
>                           color: '#5b5b5b',
>                           fontWeight: 'normal'
>                       }
>                   },
>
> ```
>             lineWidth: 1,
>             type : 'datetime',
>             dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
>                 day: '%b %e',
>                 week: '%b %e',
>                 month: '%e. %b',
>                 year: '%b'
>             },
>             tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
>             minPadding: 0.05,
>             maxPadding: 0.05,
>             labels: {
>                 rotation: (chartType == 3 ? 0 : -60),
>                 align: 'right',
>                 style: {
>                     fontSize: '14px',
>                     fontFamily: 'proxima-nova,helvetica,arial,sans-seri'
>                 }
>             }
>
>         }
> ```
>
> , `give x-axis date as Jan 1 and 00:00:00.0001` for two sample data and Jan1,00:00:00.0001,00:00:00.0002... for multiple data

Comment: How your data looks like, which interval should be?

Comment: x-axis should have irregular time interval (ie 1Nov,1Dec,1Jan...and not 00:00:00.0001,00:00:00.0002)

Comment: Please attach your data.

Comment: hi, i have jpeg how to upload here..

Comment: Why you cannot copy and paste ? jpeg will not allow us to reproduce your issue as live demo, because we have no chanve to copy it. Will be better if you will recreate your chart on jsfiddle.net.